# Visual Studio 2013 for GIT - FETCH & PULL

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

i am working with Visual Studio 2013 with a project where Git was used as source control for the project. i am working on this project from two pc.

Suppose when i made change in code in pc1 then i commit and sync to push the change to git but the same change i need to download and merge in pc2.

So when i open the same project in pc then i am not being able to find pull and fetch option. i am new in git with VS2013.

so anyone can guide me with screen shot like where to find option for **FETCH & PULL**.

**i just like to know how to reach this screen in VS2013. just see the image and tell me.**
[image]
thanks

Comment: It's immediately to the right of "Fetch", which you circled...?

Comment: the image i arrange from some web site. i just try to say i am not see the same screen in my VS2013 where pull and fetch both option should be available. so just tell me how to reach to pull and fetch both option ?